# Code being skipped after CredentialPickerResults call

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

My code is being skipped after the CredentialPickerResults call is being made. The login screen is not shown, and the code jumps to the next function, without completing the code in the current function.

It is completely skipping the Global.strUsername = credResults.CredentialUserName and the password, and going straight to GetData() function.

```
public MainPage()
{
        this.InitializeComponent();
        GetCredentials();
        GetData();
}

private async void GetCredentials()
{
    CredentialPickerOptions credOptions = new CredentialPickerOptions()
    {
         AuthenticationProtocol = AuthenticationProtocol.Basic,
         CredentialSaveOption = CredentialSaveOption.Selected,
         CallerSavesCredential = true,
         Caption = "Login",
         Message = "Please enter your credentials",
         TargetName = ".",
    };

    CredentialPickerResults credResults = await CredentialPicker.PickAsync(credOptions);

    Global.strUsername = credResults.CredentialUserName;
    Global.strPassword = credResults.CredentialPassword;
}

private async void GetData() 
{
    //get data
}
```

Comment: Its not skipping it you are simply not waiting for async operation to return a result.  You can get around this by looping on the condition that credResults is null.

Comment: How would I go about waiting for the result? Wouldn't putting it into a loop just keep calling the same call over and over again?

Comment: If the break condition for the loop is when the object is not `null` then the loop only happens once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `await` for `GetCredentials` to return. With your current code you just start it asynchronously in a "fire and forget" manner and move on to `GetData`. That's why `GetData` gets executed before `GetCredentials` completes.

You should first change the signature of both `GetCredentials` and `GetData` to return `Task`˙so that you can await them.

```
private async Task GetCredentials()
{
    // get credentials
}

private async void GetData() 
{
    // get data
}
```

Since you can't await asynchronous calls in the constructor you can work around that with a helper function which you'll call in a "fire and forget" mode, but await other calls inside it:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Init();
}

public async void Init()
{
    await GetCredentials();
    await GetData();
}
```

This way you should be able to achieve the desired behavior.